Не работает imagecreatefromwebp
Никакого ответа, когда вызываю imagecreatefromwebp. Вероятно не включен модуль или не установлен модуль GD. php8.3
Собственно как включить данный модуль и если он не установлен на текущей версии php. Как его установить, не переустанавливая php целиком?
